# how to replace only first character of a string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to replace the character 'A' of the first character of a string if the first character is 0.

> Data 01234500

> Expected output A1234500

code

results getting - A12345AA

```
string formattedId = "01234500";
if(formattedId.Substring(0,1)=="0")
formattedId = formattedId.Replace("0","A");
Console.WriteLine(formattedId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-7.0) to check the first char and [Substring(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0) to get the part after first char:

```
string formattedId = "01234500";
if (formattedId?.StartsWith("0") is true)
{
    formattedId = "A" + formattedId.Substring(1);
}
Console.WriteLine(formattedId); // Output: A1234500
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Replace()` method always changes ALL instances of the targeted string. Instead, you can do this:

```
string formattedId = "01234500";

if(formattedId[0] == '0')
{
    formattedId = "A" + formattedId.Substring(1);
}
Console.WriteLine(formattedId);
```

Comment: formattedId[0] not working , its working for formattedId.Substring(0,1)

Comment: @dotnetdev1 That's because `formattedId[0]` is only a character, not a string, which is why my answer has single quotes on the right-hand side of the equality expression. This will be significantly more efficient than the `StartsWith()` option.